# Building Simple Pyside Dialog from Sublime

Tags: python

I am testing simple pyside examples from sublime text 2.0. And when I run this simple script the window is not shown only when I just call it maximized mode ( wid.showMaximized() ).
What should be done?

This is the code:

```
# simple.py

import sys

from PySide import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

wid = QtGui.QWidget()
wid.resize(250, 150)
wid.setWindowTitle('Simple')
wid.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

go to `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Default` find `exec.py`

comment the line `startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` save the file and build the program.